# How to create a test specific Julia project dependency?

Tags: julia

Julia allows the use of a separate dependency management file for test specific dependencies. However, I am confused as to what should actually go in this file (I.e. `test/Project.toml`). Is it just the same ones at the main Project.toml file? Is it just files that we use to aide the testing process or do all of the packages from the main Project.toml file have to live in the test one as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Julia docs on test specific dependancies (https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/index.html#Test-specific-dependencies-in-Julia-1.2-and-above) it looks like the details of the relationship between the default `Project.toml` file and the `Project.toml` file for the tests is yet to be worked out.

With that said, for the test specific file, you just need to include the packages which are required to run the tests you have specified. For example, if you use the `Benchmark` and `Images` packages for the tests, those need to be in the test specific `Project.toml` file.